# In IE mimeType not set sometimes to determine correct hight and width of svg image

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, svg, mime-types

I run into a bug which was and still is hard to reproduce. Following function:

```
function getNaturalImgDim(image) {
    var src = image.attr("src");
    // create a shadow image for ie purposes to load the image and determine
    // the dimensions
    var offscreenImg = $('<img>').attr("src", src);
    var imageWidth = null;
    var imageHeight = null;
    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv:11\./) 
         && (image[0].mimeType.indexOf('SVG') >= 0 ||
             image[0].mimeType.indexOf('scalable vector graphics') >= 0)) {
            //this is a special code for IE 11
            //the "inmemory" offscreen image doesn't get load by ie11 before it's attached to the DOM. See "appendTo" below
            offscreenImg.css({
                position : "absolute",
                top : "10000px",
                left : "10000px"
            }).appendTo('body');

            imageWidth = offscreenImg.width();
            imageHeight = offscreenImg.height();

            //remove the dummy image after the dimension is determined
            offscreenImg.remove();
    }else{
        imageWidth = offscreenImg[0].width;
        imageHeight = offscreenImg[0].height;
    }       
    offscreenImg = null;        
    return new Point(imageWidth, imageHeight);
}
```

As you can see I am determining the dimension of an img tag. I have special treatment for svg in IE. This works for chrome, firefox and (apparently some times) IE.

I found out that some times the mimeType is set and some times it is not. To make it more confusing. If the mimeType is not set in IE it goes to else case and reads width and height. So, here some times the width and height can be determined and sometimes it delivers 0.

I hope someone could point to a direction why the strange behavior happens.

Comment: you presumably need to wait for the onload event of the image. Without that you have a race condition on all UAs.

Comment: Hey Robert, the above function will be executed within an interval of 200 ms for one minute. At some point the image is loaded. so guess no race condition

Comment: I see no evidence of your assertion. Your code does not wait between setting the src attribute and trying to read the image height/width.

Comment: You are right, there is no code above between setting src and reading height and width. But the function is called with an img tag which already has the src. The function is called within an interval. so the provided src tag is as html included. The src should be at some point loaded.

Comment: And when you set the attribute again the UA is free to discard and reload your image so you're back to the race condition.